# Problem connecting to Elastic Search using client in Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I just started with Elastic and I have to write a program for a project and it connects to Elastic and the lamb brings me a table but when I write the code and start testing it returns the client null.

The elastic configuration was done in the project and I did not configure the elastic at all and just autowired the configured elastic class in my class.

```
public EventTest findByEventTestSerial(String serial) {

    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("deleted", false))
            .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("serial", serial));
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch()
            .setIndices(def_index_name)
            .setTypes(Constants.Elastic.DOC_TYPE)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.constantScoreQuery(boolQueryBuilder))
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
    return findSingle(response);
}
```

Comment: I just entered the project and realized that this project uses elastic. This program is supposed to read the data of a table from Elastic database, but I am still involved in Elastic connection and I can not test my cod